# Nested JSON Parsing through URL in android using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

first time I am giving hands on JSON Parsing.I am trying to retrieve the data from a URL and parsing it using Volley.But I am not getting the data.
My code :

```
            package com.example.hp.citysearchapp;

        import android.app.DownloadManager;
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.android.volley.Request;
        import com.android.volley.Response;
        import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
        import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;

        public class CityDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            public static String url;
            String getId;
            TextView tv;
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_details);
                tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                    getId = bundle.getString("gettingId");

                url="http://test.maheshwari.org/services/testwebservice.asmx/GetCity?cityId="+getId

              JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                      try {

          String citycode = jsonObject.getString("CityCode");     //problem line , no string received here
                          Toast.makeText(CityDetailsActivity.this,citycode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
              }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                  }
              });

            }

            private void hidePDialog() {
                if (pDialog != null) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    pDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

The data I am getting from the URL is of this type :

```
{
 "CityCode": 374,
  "State": {
"StateCode": 29,
"CountryCode": 1,
"Country": {
  "CountryCode": 1,
  "IsdCode": "+91"
}
 },
 "Country": {
"CountryCode": 1,
"CountryName": "India",
"IsdCode": "+91"
 },
 "GPlaceId": "ChIJgeJXTN9KbDkRCS7yDDrG4Qw",
 "Latitude": 26.912434,
 "Longitude": 75.787271,
 "ActiveStatus": 1
}
```

Please also help me woth the nested json parsing  , ie, how to retrieve the variable "CountryCode".

Comment: CountryCode which is inside the Country Object inside the State object.

Comment: What does `Log.d("TAG", jsonObject.toString())` show, is the response logged same as you are expecting?

Comment: The Log.d() shows nothing .No Log appears for that "TAG" . @Sourabh

Comment: Is your Response.ErrorListener() being called, if so what is the error?

Comment: No,it is not called. @bucezk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't need to send a JSON object in your request, use a `StringRequest` as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://<your URL>";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        //I'm basically displaying the skeleton code. You have to put try/catch clauses when required.
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        Integer cityCode = json.optInt("CityCode");
        String cityName = json.optString("CityName");
        JSONObject state = json.optJSONObject("State");
        String stateName = state.optString("StateName");
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: How I will get the CityCode ,StateCode and other parameters ?

Comment: Did my answer get you a json response?

Comment: Yeah !! I am getting the response through this method. But now how to get those parameters ? @RuchiraRandana

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer so that you can get the value of cityCode, cityName and stateName. You can have a look at my code and complete the rest I guess!

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out few minutes ago.Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
String countryCode = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Country").getInt("CountryCode");
```

Answer (score 0):

If i don't remember wrong Volley works best with String's. You are using double and int's all over the place so to make your life easier you could make all values in he JSON object String's.

This is how i do it and then convert from String to whatever you need in your application. See below for example.

```
{
"CityCode": "374",
"State": {
"StateCode": "29",
"CountryCode": "1",
"Country": {
"CountryCode": "1",
"IsdCode": "+91"
}
},
"Country": {
"CountryCode": "1",
"CountryName": "India",
"IsdCode": "+91"
},
"GPlaceId": "ChIJgeJXTN9KbDkRCS7yDDrG4Qw",
"Latitude": "26.912434",
"Longitude": "75.787271",
"ActiveStatus": "1"
}
```